# Firefox does not recognize my Stylesheets

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

I'm just writing a framework for responsive web development. I just started yesterday and began with the css today. Everything works fine in Chrome as well as in IE, but Firefox doesn't recognize the stylsheets at all.
I did validate everything and didn't get any errors.
This is the way I integrated the CSS:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/WebDesign/Projects/Framework/css/reset.css" />
```

Oh, and maybe it's important: I only used the `<!DOCTYPE html>` as declaration.
Thanks for any answer :)

Comment: could you share your stylesheet?

Comment: Install Firebug, and go to the `net` tab, to see if it's actually finding the file. Your path seems wrong. surely `css/reset.css` would be better?

Comment: Post your whole `.html` file as well.

Comment: Check your error console for error messages. You may have a server misconfiguration.

Comment: Could be possibly where you're calling your file from. Maybe take away the first `/`?

Comment: I actually have 13 stylesheets, I'm gonna send one of them.
css/reset.css was my acutal path, but it didn't work. My IDE and all my project is on an USB drive

Comment: Definitely you should check if the browser is correctly retrieving the stylesheet

Comment: deleting the firs / didn't work

Comment: starting with `/` means to start from url root. So if you are browsing the file in something like... `localhost/myWebsite/index.html`, the css will be looked into `localhost/WebDesign/Projects/(...)`. Anyways, too little info to actually find the error. Post the html or other thing.

Comment: Firefox says it only found 3 CSS rules, and all of them are ones I included with an inline stylesheet.

Comment: What is the layout of your project folder?  You should like the CSS relative to the current HTML file.

Comment: Projects > Framework
Framework has the index.html in it and two other folders called javascript and css.
index.html is the file were talking about all the time

Comment: So then all you should need is `css/stylesheet-name.css` because `index.html` is in the root, and you have a `css` folder in that root folder, containing your stylesheets.

Comment: Can you open just css file in the browser? [your domain]/WebDesign/Projects/Framework/css/reset.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the style sheet is in the same root, you don't really need the whole link to the root when getting the style:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/CSS" />
```